# Jquery evaluating 2 time fields

Tags: jquery

I have a form which contains two dropdown lists, From time and To time.
Both lists display the hours in 24 hour format but the hour values are are plain numbers without any leading zeros.

When I try to evaluate and make sure the user is selecting a "To" hour that it is greater than the "From" hour I keep getting the alert that "From" hour" must be less than the "to" hour.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with my evaluation script.

```
function getvalHT(sel) {
    var selectedFromHours   = $('#RoomFromTimeH').val();
    var selectedToHours     = $('#RoomToTimeH').val();

    console.log(selectedFromHours);
    console.log(selectedToHours);

    var selectedFromMin     = $('#RoomFromTimeM').val();
    var selectedToMin       = $('#RoomToTimeM').val();

    if(selectedFromHours > selectedToHours) {
        $("#savebutton").show(); 
    }else {
        $.alert({
            title: 'Time period error!',
            content: 'The "From" hours time of ' + $('#RoomFromTimeH').val() + '<BR/><BR/> must be less than<BR/><BR/> the "To" hours time of ' + $('#RoomToTimeH').val() + '.',
            icon: 'fa fa-rocket',
            animation: 'zoom',
            boxWidth: '50%',
            closeAnimation: 'zoom',
            buttons: {
             okay: {
                text: 'Try again',
                btnClass: 'btn-blue'
             }
            },

                cancel: function () {
                 $.alert('canceled');
            }
       });
        $("#savebutton").hide();  // any other condition hide the button
        $('#RoomFromTimeH').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#RoomToTimeH').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#RoomFromTimeM').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#RoomToTimeM').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working just fine for me! See example below.

And may I just add to this that it might be more userfriendly to just disable the hours in the second select that are lower than the value selected in the first select? This will prevent annoying popup errors for your end users.

```js
$('.selectTime').change(function() {

  var selectedFromHours = $('#RoomFromTimeH').val();
  var selectedToHours = $('#RoomToTimeH').val();

  console.log(selectedFromHours);
  console.log(selectedToHours);

  var selectedFromMin = $('#RoomFromTimeM').val();
  var selectedToMin = $('#RoomToTimeM').val();

  if (selectedFromHours < selectedToHours) {

    $("#savebutton").show();

  } else {

    $.alert({
      title: 'Time period error!',
      content: 'The "From" hours time of ' + $('#RoomFromTimeH').val() + '<BR/><BR/> must be less than<BR/><BR/> the "To" hours time of ' + $('#RoomToTimeH').val() + '.',
      icon: 'fa fa-rocket',
      animation: 'zoom',
      boxWidth: '50%',
      closeAnimation: 'zoom',
      buttons: {
        okay: {
          text: 'Try again',
          btnClass: 'btn-blue'
        }
      },

      cancel: function() {
        $.alert('canceled');
      }
    });

    $("#savebutton").hide(); // any other condition hide the button
    $('#RoomFromTimeH').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#RoomToTimeH').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#RoomFromTimeM').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#RoomToTimeM').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  }

});
```

```css
/*!
 * jquery-confirm v3.1.0 (http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)
 * Author: boniface pereira
 * Website: www.craftpip.com
 * Contact: hey@craftpip.com
 *
 * Copyright 2013-2017 jquery-confirm
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */@-webkit-keyframes jconfirm-spin{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes jconfirm-spin{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}body[class*=jconfirm-no-scroll-]{overflow:hidden!important}.jconfirm{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:99999999;font-family:inherit;overflow:hidden}.jconfirm .jconfirm-bg{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;-webkit-transition:opacity .4s;transition:opacity .4s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-bg.jconfirm-bg-h{opacity:0!important}.jconfirm .jconfirm-scrollpane{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow-y:auto;-webkit-perspective:500px;perspective:500px;-webkit-perspective-origin:center;perspective-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box{background:white;border-radius:4px;position:relative;outline:0;padding:15px 15px 0;overflow:hidden}@-webkit-keyframes type-blue{1%,100%{border-color:#3498db}50%{border-color:#5faee3}}@keyframes type-blue{1%,100%{border-color:#3498db}50%{border-color:#5faee3}}@-webkit-keyframes type-green{1%,100%{border-color:#2ecc71}50%{border-color:#54d98c}}@keyframes type-green{1%,100%{border-color:#2ecc71}50%{border-color:#54d98c}}@-webkit-keyframes type-red{1%,100%{border-color:#e74c3c}50%{border-color:#ed7669}}@keyframes type-red{1%,100%{border-color:#e74c3c}50%{border-color:#ed7669}}@-webkit-keyframes type-orange{1%,100%{border-color:#f1c40f}50%{border-color:#f4d03f}}@keyframes type-orange{1%,100%{border-color:#f1c40f}50%{border-color:#f4d03f}}@-webkit-keyframes type-purple{1%,100%{border-color:#9b59b6}50%{border-color:#b07cc6}}@keyframes type-purple{1%,100%{border-color:#9b59b6}50%{border-color:#b07cc6}}@-webkit-keyframes type-dark{1%,100%{border-color:#34495e}50%{border-color:#46627f}}@keyframes type-dark{1%,100%{border-color:#34495e}50%{border-color:#46627f}}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-animated{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-iteration-count:infinite}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-blue{border-top:solid 7px #3498db;-webkit-animation-name:type-blue;animation-name:type-blue}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-green{border-top:solid 7px #2ecc71;-webkit-animation-name:type-green;animation-name:type-green}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-red{border-top:solid 7px #e74c3c;-webkit-animation-name:type-red;animation-name:type-red}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-orange{border-top:solid 7px #f1c40f;-webkit-animation-name:type-orange;animation-name:type-orange}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-purple{border-top:solid 7px #9b59b6;-webkit-animation-name:type-purple;animation-name:type-purple}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-type-dark{border-top:solid 7px #34495e;-webkit-animation-name:type-dark;animation-name:type-dark}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.loading{height:120px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.loading:before{content:'';position:absolute;left:0;background:white;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;border-radius:10px;z-index:1}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.loading:after{opacity:.6;content:'';height:30px;width:30px;border:solid 3px transparent;position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-15px;border-radius:50%;-webkit-animation:jconfirm-spin 1s infinite linear;animation:jconfirm-spin 1s infinite linear;border-bottom-color:dodgerblue;top:50%;margin-top:-15px;z-index:2}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon{height:20px;width:20px;position:absolute;top:5px;right:5px;cursor:pointer;opacity:.6;text-align:center;-webkit-transition:opacity .3s ease-in;transition:opacity .3s ease-in;font-size:27px!important;line-height:14px!important;display:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon:empty{display:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon .fa{font-size:16px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon .glyphicon{font-size:16px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon .zmdi{font-size:16px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon:hover{opacity:1}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c{display:block;font-size:22px;line-height:20px;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c.jconfirm-hand{cursor:move}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c .jconfirm-icon-c{font-size:inherit;padding-bottom:15px;display:inline-block;margin-right:8px;vertical-align:middle}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c .jconfirm-icon-c i{vertical-align:middle}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c .jconfirm-icon-c:empty{display:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c .jconfirm-title{-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;font-size:inherit;font-family:inherit;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;padding-bottom:15px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c .jconfirm-title:empty{display:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content-pane{margin-bottom:15px;height:auto;-webkit-transition:height .4s ease-in;transition:height .4s ease-in;display:inline-block;width:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content-pane .jconfirm-content img{max-width:100%;height:auto}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content-pane .jconfirm-content:empty{display:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{padding-bottom:11px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons>button{margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:2px;margin-right:2px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.42857143;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle;-ms-touch-action:manipulation;touch-action:manipulation;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;border-radius:4px;min-height:1em;outline:0;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-transition:opacity .1s ease,background-color .1s ease,color .1s ease,box-shadow .1s ease,background .1s ease;transition:opacity .1s ease,background-color .1s ease,color .1s ease,box-shadow .1s ease,background .1s ease;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;border:0;background-image:none}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-blue{background-color:#3498db;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-blue:hover{background-color:#2980b9;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-green{background-color:#2ecc71;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-green:hover{background-color:#27ae60;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-red{background-color:#e74c3c;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-red:hover{background-color:#c0392b;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-orange{background-color:#f1c40f;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-orange:hover{background-color:#f39c12;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default{background-color:#ecf0f1;color:#000;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default:hover{background-color:#bdc3c7;color:#000}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-purple{background-color:#9b59b6;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-purple:hover{background-color:#8e44ad;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-dark{background-color:#34495e;color:#FFF;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .2s;transition:background .2s}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-dark:hover{background-color:#2c3e50;color:#FFF}.jconfirm .jconfirm-clear{clear:both}.jconfirm.jconfirm-rtl{direction:rtl}.jconfirm.jconfirm-rtl div.jconfirm-closeIcon{left:5px;right:auto}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-bg,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-bg{background-color:#444;opacity:.2}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-box,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-box{margin:0 auto;box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border-radius:5px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{float:right}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:none}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default{box-shadow:none;color:#333}.jconfirm.jconfirm-white .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default:hover,.jconfirm.jconfirm-light .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default:hover{background:#ddd}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-bg,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-bg{background-color:darkslategray;opacity:.4}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-box,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-box{box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);background:#444;border-radius:5px;color:white}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{float:right}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{border:0;background-image:none;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:background .1s;transition:background .1s;color:white}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default{box-shadow:none;color:#fff;background:0}.jconfirm.jconfirm-black .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default:hover,.jconfirm.jconfirm-dark .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button.btn-default:hover{background:#666}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.hilight.jconfirm-hilight-shake{-webkit-animation:shake .82s cubic-bezier(0.36,0.07,0.19,0.97) both;animation:shake .82s cubic-bezier(0.36,0.07,0.19,0.97) both;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.hilight.jconfirm-hilight-glow{-webkit-animation:glow .82s cubic-bezier(0.36,0.07,0.19,0.97) both;animation:glow .82s cubic-bezier(0.36,0.07,0.19,0.97) both;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}@-webkit-keyframes shake{10%,90%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-2px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-2px,0,0)}20%,80%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(4px,0,0);transform:translate3d(4px,0,0)}30%,50%,70%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-8px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-8px,0,0)}40%,60%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(8px,0,0);transform:translate3d(8px,0,0)}}@keyframes shake{10%,90%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-2px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-2px,0,0)}20%,80%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(4px,0,0);transform:translate3d(4px,0,0)}30%,50%,70%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-8px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-8px,0,0)}40%,60%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(8px,0,0);transform:translate3d(8px,0,0)}}@-webkit-keyframes glow{0%,100%{box-shadow:0 0 3px red}50%{box-shadow:0 0 30px red}}@keyframes glow{0%,100%{box-shadow:0 0 3px red}50%{box-shadow:0 0 30px red}}.jconfirm{-webkit-perspective:400px;perspective:400px}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box{opacity:1;-webkit-transition-property:all;transition-property:all}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-top,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-left,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-right,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-bottom,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-opacity,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-zoom,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scale,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-none,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotate,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotatex,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotatey,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scaley,.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scalex{opacity:0}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotate{-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);transform:rotate(90deg)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotatex{-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);transform:rotateX(90deg);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotatexr{-webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg);transform:rotateX(-90deg);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotatey{-webkit-transform:rotatey(90deg);-ms-transform:rotatey(90deg);transform:rotatey(90deg);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-rotateyr{-webkit-transform:rotatey(-90deg);-ms-transform:rotatey(-90deg);transform:rotatey(-90deg);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scaley{-webkit-transform:scaley(1.5);-ms-transform:scaley(1.5);transform:scaley(1.5);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scalex{-webkit-transform:scalex(1.5);-ms-transform:scalex(1.5);transform:scalex(1.5);-webkit-transform-origin:center;-ms-transform-origin:center;transform-origin:center}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-top{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-100px);-ms-transform:translate(0px,-100px);transform:translate(0px,-100px)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-left{-webkit-transform:translate(-100px,0px);-ms-transform:translate(-100px,0px);transform:translate(-100px,0px)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-right{-webkit-transform:translate(100px,0px);-ms-transform:translate(100px,0px);transform:translate(100px,0px)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-bottom{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,100px);-ms-transform:translate(0px,100px);transform:translate(0px,100px)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-zoom{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);-ms-transform:scale(1.2);transform:scale(1.2)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-scale{-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-ms-transform:scale(0.5);transform:scale(0.5)}.jconfirm .jconfirm-box.jconfirm-animation-none{visibility:hidden}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-bg{background-color:rgba(54,70,93,0.95)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box{background-color:transparent}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon{color:white}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c{text-align:center;color:white;font-size:28px;font-weight:normal}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c>*{padding-bottom:25px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content-pane{margin-bottom:25px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content{text-align:center;color:white}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{text-align:center}.jconfirm.jconfirm-supervan .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{font-size:16px;border-radius:2px;background:#303f53;text-shadow:none;border:0;color:white;padding:10px;min-width:100px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-bg{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.67)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box{background-color:white;box-shadow:0 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 13px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 5px 24px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);padding:30px 25px 10px 25px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);font-size:22px;font-weight:bold}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content{text-align:left;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{text-align:right}.jconfirm.jconfirm-material .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-bg{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.21)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box{background-color:white;box-shadow:0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);padding:15px 0 0}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-closeIcon{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87)}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-title-c{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content{text-align:left;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);padding:0 15px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons{text-align:right;padding:0;margin:-5px 0 0;border-top:solid 1px #ddd;overflow:hidden;border-radius:0 0 4px 4px}.jconfirm.jconfirm-bootstrap .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{font-weight:500;border-radius:0;margin:0;border-left:solid 1px #ddd}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.1.1/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<select id="RoomFromTimeH" class="selectTime">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
</select>
<select id="RoomToTimeH" class="selectTime">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
</select>

<button id="savebutton" style="display:none;">Save</button>
```

Comment: hi and thanks for your reply. When I run the code snippet, if I select 01 from the From and 03 from the To the time period error is fired. So that does not work because 3 is greater than 1 so the alert should not fire.

Comment: OK so the FROM time has to be smaller than the TO time? Then why do you have `if (selectedFromHours > selectedToHours) {}`? Haha :-)

Comment: I changed it to `if (selectedFromHours < selectedToHours) {}` in my answer above. See if this is the behaviour you wanted.

Comment: I'm getting the idea that you'll feel pretty stupid in a few seconds, and me as well, if all it took was changing a > to a < and I wrote this super long answer, haha!

Comment: You are so right, completely stupid. So sorry for not spotting that.

Comment: Haha no problem :) Could you still please mark my answer as the solution maybe :-P?

Comment: for sure I will.

Comment: just found an issue. If you extend the pisk list to include 1 to 23 for both the from and the to lists, select say 02 from the first list and then select anythng above 09 from the second list, the alert is fired.

Comment: Changed a part of the code to convert sting to int, it works.
var selectedFromHours = parseInt($('#RoomFromTimeH').val());
 var selectedToHours = parseInt($('#RoomToTimeH').val());